# ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

I am trying to overwrite a row in one dataframe based on a row in another dataframe. Open to alternative approaches!

This loop runs 15 times then errors. Strange. The same kind of loop runs just fine within the same function.

```py
for row in rows_unique:
    print(row in df_a.index) # all True...
    print(row in df_b.index) # all True...
    
    df_a.loc[row] = df_b.loc[row]
```

Here is the tail of the trace

```py
~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/jupyterlab3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    690 
    691         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 692         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    693 
    694     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/jupyterlab3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1635             self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1636         else:
-> 1637             self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
   1638 
   1639     def _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name: str):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/jupyterlab3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_single_block(self, indexer, value, name)
   1852 
   1853         elif isinstance(value, ABCDataFrame) and name != "iloc":
-> 1854             value = self._align_frame(indexer, value)
   1855 
   1856         # check for chained assignment

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/jupyterlab3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _align_frame(self, indexer, df)
   2080             return val
   2081 
-> 2082         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with DataFrame")
   2083 
   2084 

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

Trace is really iloc focused.

pandas v1.2.3

Comment: Can you provide minimal sample frames of `df_a` and `df_b` to have something to reproduce this behaviour ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: if it runs for some rows and not the others, maybe some `row` are actually index of several rows. and for an alternative, you can try `df_a.update(df_b)` that overwrite values in df_a with index and column alignment

Comment: Actually yes, if in `df_b` you have several `row` in index, then I could reproduce your error

Comment: first i'll check that indices are unique and then try update. big files.

Comment: update won't work either if duplicated index in df_b

Comment: bingo. df_b's index was not unique. thank you!